# How do I add an image to a label in AmChart5?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

In data I have a [am5.Picture](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/picture/) object

```js
icon = am5.Picture.new(root, {
    height: 28,
    src: src
});
```

The image fits on the text, is not inserted next to it

[image]

this doesn't work either

```js
series.labels.template.set("text", "{icon} {name}") // return only name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [Container](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/container/)

```js
series.labels.values.forEach((label, index) => {
            if (label.dataItem.dataContext.icon) {
                let container = am5.Container.new(root, {
                    layout: root.horizontalLayout
                })
                container.children.push(label.dataItem.dataContext.icon)
                container.children.push(
                    am5.Label.new(root, {
                        text: label.dataItem.dataContext.name,
                        fontSize: 10,
                        textAlign: "left",
                        centerY: am5.percent(50),
                        paddingLeft: 5,
                    })
                )
                label.children.clear()
                label.children.push(container)
            } else {
                label.setAll({
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fontWeight: "300",
                    textAlign: "left",
                    maxWidth: 260,
                    oversizedBehavior: "wrap",
                    text: "{name}"
                })
            }
        })
```